# Unrelated attribute error The value of attribute "unrelated" must be set

Tags: magento2, error, custom-attributes

#### Preconditions

1. Magento 2.1.4
2. CenOS 6.9, MySQL 5.6.35, PHP 7.0.17, Apache 2.4.25

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Go to Products - Add Product - Grouped Product - and create a product based on an attribute set you know does not include certain attributes.
2. Fill out the pertinent information for the product and then add products to group.
3. Select a number of Simple Products (not visible individually)
4. Add pictures and then Save.

#### Expected result

1. The Grouped Product should be created

#### Actual result

1. An error message appears "The value of attribute "bra_band_size" must be set, an attribute that is not being used to create the Grouped Product.
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nqysiff600qonj/Unrelated%20value%20of%20attribute%20error.mp4?dl=0

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Go to Products - Add Product - Grouped Product - and create a product based on an attribute set you know does not include certain attributes.
2. Fill out the pertinent information for the product and then save the product without adding any products to the Group
3. Save the product

#### Expected result

1. The Grouped Product should not be saved

#### Actual result

1. The error message does not appear if you do not include any products to Group and saves without issues.
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/5gtf4rxn10sp5os/grouped%20product%20is%20saved%20when%20no%20product%20is%20included.mp4?dl=0

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Open the Grouped Product that was saved without any products added.
2. Add the products to Group and then save.

#### Expected result

1. The Grouped Product should not save and have the same attribute related error message.

#### Actual result

1. The Grouped Product is saved, but it is shown as out of stock despite all of the added Products are in stock.
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/jl9vm8xroy0ei3x/product%20can%20be%20added%20later%20but%20shown%20as%20out%20of%20stock.mp4?dl=0